# Why is the end date for one more day？

Tags: fullcalendar

```
select: function(start, end) {
var formatStart = start.format();
var formatEnd = end.format();
alert(formatEnd);
showProjModal(formatStart,formatEnd);
},
```

i choice 2016-08-11 to 2016-08-13,but formatEnd is 2016-08-14,i do not know why?

Comment: How could such a question receive TWO upvotes??! For what recondite reason??? 
... Anyway, it would help us a lot if you post your entire JS code, and would be best if you provide a "working" fiddle where your error is reproduced

Answer (score 4):

From the docs at [fullcalendar.io](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/).

`end is a Moment indicating the end of the selection. It is an exclusive value, so if the selection is all-day, and the last day is a Thursday, end will be Friday.`

I guess your selection is all day? So it is working as intended.

You can check this by calling [hasTime](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/#ambiguously-timed)

Example

```
if (end.hasTime()) {
    // Specific endpoint. For example 2016-07-13 10:00:00'
}
else {
    // All day. For example 2016-07-13
    // If you want to output the end day you selected here subtract 1 of the day
    end.subtract(1, 'days');
}
```